# No compilation error comparing integer with string?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Probably like many, I typed this typo

```
int a = 0;
cout << a < " "; //note the '<'
```

However, the MSVC++ compiler threw just a warning

> warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with
>   side-effect

though I expected a compilation error. Is it indeed standard complaint code? Does any implicit type conversion or overloading happen which make the code valid? I am also confused whether `<` operator is comparing the string `" "` with an integer `a` or with the result of `cout << a`

A related SO post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665611/why-does-this-code-produce-a-warning-referring-to-the-comma-operator).

Comment: The compiler you're using accepts pointer and integral types comparisons but the standard forbids this. Update or change compiler if necessary

Comment: @a.lasram And how would the "NULL" macro work if it didn't?

Comment: @a.lasram It doesn’t. You got the precedence mixed up.

Comment: @kfsone Completely unrelated, `NULL` is a special case since literal-0 (but *only* literal-0) can be implicitly converted to a pointer.

Comment: There is nothing special about NULL, it's a macro defined as 0. And he tested against zero. This is why C++11 adds "nullptr" and "std::nullptr_t".

Comment: @kfsone good observation about the NULL constant but it's an integral const not a pointer [conv.ptr] as Konrad Rudolph pointed. Also I'm out of subject since the problem is '<<' that precedes '<', again as Konrad Rudolph pointed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<<` operator has a higher precedence than `<`, so this is parsed as

```
(cout << a) < " ";
```

You are not really comparing a string with an integer. Instead, you are comparing the return value of `ostream::operator<<`, which is `std::cout` itself, to the string literal. This isn't legal (in the sense that is has an unspecified result, and it is not meaningful) either, `clang` warns:

```
warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified
```

The reason why it compiles is that up until C++11, `std::ostream` can be implicitly converted to `void *`. Also, the string literal of type `const char[2]` decays into a pointer of type `const char *`. So, the `<` operator now takes two pointers, which is permitted, although its result is not specified, because the two pointers don't point to the same object.

Comment: Unspecified != illegal.

Comment: @jrok I wouldn't consider anything legal which emits a compiler warning, nor something that *doesn't do what one thinks it does* (roughly).

Comment: quick question: does overloading has any effect on the precedence of the operator? ( << is overloaded above )

Comment: @winterlight No, it doesn't - [link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161049/can-i-change-operator-precedence-and-associativity-in-c).

Comment: @H2CO3, I saw this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945142/operator-overloading-and-precedence) (albeit related C#), then felt << had higher precedence because it is overloaded not just because non-overloaded << has more precedence over <

Comment: @H2CO3 To be clear: this is **legal** on C++03. The compiler *may* warn but it *must not* emit an error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Of course, that's right. (I tend to be stricter than the compiler, I don't like syntactically legal things that don't make sense because they eventually cause confusion.)

Comment: Someone please pat h2co3 on the back for being stricter than compiler :D

Comment: @jrok LOL, lot of SO newcomers already do that virtually for my sometimes-snarky comments :P

Comment: @H2CO3: Not liking syntactically things that don't make sense is great, but you don't get to say they're *illegal*. Actually the C++ standard doesn't use the word "illegal", but I'd say something is illegal if and only if a conforming compiler is required to diagnose it. In C, that's syntax errors and constraint violations; I think C++ uses different terminology.

Comment: @KeithThompson And that's why I didn't say "it's a syntax error" or "it's a constraint violation" - it's neither. Our notion of "legal" and "illegal" might be slightly different, I **intentionally** didn't use the Standard's wording, because I was not talking about that.

Comment: @H2CO3: My point is that using the word "illegal" to refer to things that a compiler may or may not warn about is a misuse of the word. Perhaps "incorrect" is closer to the idea you're expressing.

Comment: @KeithThompson Okay, I accept that - won't change the answer for now, though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The compiler can emit an error even if the code is legal.  It may not refuse to compile the code, however

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out _why_ this is formally legal.  The return value of `x << y` is a `std::ostream&`.  There is no operator `<` which takes an `std::ostream` as its left operand, so the compiler looks for conversions.  In pre C++11, there was a conversion `std::istream` to `void*`.  And pointer comparisons are legal (although the results are unspecified unless the two pointers point into the same object, which wouldn't be the case here).  I think C++11 has fixed this.

Comment: @KeithThompson C++ uses distinctly different wording, but the end result is very similar.  C++ does pick up a few cases that C doesn't, but very few---on the whole, it's far to easy to get undefined behavior with either.  (Although here, the behavior isn't undefined, but just unspecified.)

Comment: @JamesKanze "It's probably worth pointing out why this is formally legal" - Agreed, I'm adding it. It's not at all obvious.

Comment: @James Yes, C++11 changed that, see comments under Ed Heal’s answer.

Comment: An interesting point: Given `void *p0; const char *p1;`, it appears that the expression `p0 < p1` is valid in C++; both operands are implicitly converted to their *composite pointer type*, which in this case is `const void*`. In C, the same comparison is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic from the compiler. It's a little surprising to see a stronger type-checking rule in C than in C++. (C++11 didn't change this rule; it dropped the implicit conversion of `std::ostream*` to `void*`, so the rule no longer applies in this particular case.)

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos. Your phrase "up until C++03" could imply that it became invalid in C++03; I didn't change that (partly because I'm uncertain when that change was made), but you might want to reconsider that wording. If it was C++11 that changed the rule, "up until C++11" might express the meaning more clearly.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you. Changed phrasing to "up until C++11".

Comment: @KeithThompson One could argue that in this case,
C overspecifies; that instead of "compatible object type", it
should say something along the lines of one being convertible to
the other.  The semantics of the operators _do_ describe what
would happen in such cases (e.g. `struct { double d; int i; } x;
if ( &x.d < &x.i )`  This violates the constraint, but §6.5.8/5
describes the the semantics for it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: One could, but I wouldn't. I'd argue that a comparison of pointers of different types is likely to be an error (as in this question); if you want to do such a comparison, you can always cast one of the operands.

Comment: @KeithThompson "cast one of the operands": to what, in my example?  Both to `void*`?  (Not that it's a big point, since in a `struct`, you _know_ the order.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Perhaps `char*`, though `void*` works in C++ (and apparently in C11 -- hmm). But knowing a sensible type to cast one or both operands to requires that the comparison is sensible in the first place. In the OP's code, it isn't. For members of the same struct object, `offsetof` is probably a better solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Off-topic for this question, but on re-reading the relevant sections of the C90, C99, and C11 standards, I see that relational operators (`<` et al) on two `void*` operands is valid in all versions of the standard: "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible incomplete types". There's no implicit conversion from `foo*` to `void*` in that context. So casting to `void*` makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, since it is `(cout << a) < " "`, we're comparing an `ostream` with `" "`. The `ostream` class has an operator to convert it to `void *`. You can compare a `void *` with a `const char *` without cast, so the compiler is happily doing that, then realizing that you are not using the result of the comparison, and issues the warning.

One of those quirky things in C++.

Comment: But @Ed Heal said that `ostream` object does not have an overloaded `<`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Correct, it hasn't. So the compiler finds a conversion to a type that can be compared - in this case an `operator (void *)`.

Comment: `ostream` *had* an `operator void*()`, but no longer.

Answer (score 1):

It is down to operator [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

i.e.

The line equates to `(cout << a) < " ";` - Hence the `<" "` does nothing!

**EDIT**

This bit returns an object `(cout << a)` returns an object of type `ostream` where it does not have an overloaded operator `<`, so either the compiler gives up (C++11) or scratches its head amd has a bash at the integer operator (i.e. pointers etc).

Comment: @H2CO3 Or rather, why it doesn’t work any more *in C++11*. Before C++11, it works just fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph My thought too, but g++ and clang [compile it anyway](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=592bdf2c9761344094107a5d3ade5fdf-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419).

Comment: If it matters, I am using MSVC++ 2010, and it seems to have many C++11 features, but probably not fully complaint to it.

Comment: @jrok The stdlibc++ implementation is buggy. The standard states that `std::basic_ios` no longer contains `operator void*() const`, instead it has `explicit operator bool() const` (§27.5.5.1). [Using libc++ with clang++ does the right thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ec4ed071b65114b32cdec66752b75c8d-e50ba9fcf11a6b0c9e1992e63673f963).