# Operator Precedence Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, c++14

Why can you not change the operator precedence when you overload operators in C++? For example, if you had a class in which it would make sense to do addition before multiplication, how could you make the addition operator have higher precedence than the multiplication one?

This is different from this question [Operator overloading and precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945142/operator-overloading-and-precedence)
because I am asking why, and how to work around this restriction.

I would prefer to avoid compiler customization, and use only C++14 standards. Third-party libraries are OK.

Comment: *"Why can you not change the operator precedence when you overload operators in C++?"* Standard says so. *"how to work around this restriction"* You can't.

Comment: I doubt there is a feasible workaround.

Comment: Mostly because traditional compiler design parses the grammar and the syntax of the code first. Only after it's parsed, does the C++ compiler tries to figure out where each operator comes from, built-in, or overloaded. By that time, the horse has already left the barn.

Comment: Use regular member functions to enforce an order.

Comment: But why does the standard specify this?

Comment: Because the standard actually wants to make it possible to write a C++ compiler in the first place, using tools that have been around even before C++ existed.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: Also worth saying, I think, that if you are overloading `+` and `*` in a way which would change their natural precedence order, then you have chosen unnatural definitions of `+` and `*`, and you would also confuse human beings reading the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditional compiler design parses the grammar first, before figuring out where each operator comes from.

Compiler design tools like [YACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) existed long before C++. As such, traditional compilers evolved over time following the general principle of parsing the syntax of the source code first, then trying to figure out what to do with each operator. So, the compiler sees the structure of the language first, and foremost; and the C++ standard actually wants to make it possible to write a C++ compiler without reinventing every wheel that has been invented, already.

Comment: C++ is difficult enough to parse already, without always knowing whether a given symbol is a type, or an actual object, depending on the context...

Comment: Ok. I get it. Thanks for the responses.